# Why Enums doesn't return real numbers?

Tags: c#, enums

Enums are something I really love to implement in my code, but I want to know why [Enums](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbbt4032.aspx) are limited to **byte, sbyte, short, ushort, int, uint, long, or ulong** as return type.

Lets say we have a scenario, where we need to get a discount according to the discount type,

```
public enum DiscountType : float
{
    Student = 10.5,
    SeniorCitizen = 15.5,
    BeautifulWomen = 25.5,
    SmartGuy = 25.5
}
```

I know there are several ways to implement this requirement (example using Structs). But I'll be really interested to do with Enums, is it Possible ? If not Why Enums are Restricted ?

Comment: you have to ask the .net architect :)

Comment: Why cant you just use constant values for this? I dont see the advantage of an enum here.

Comment: I would use a `Dictionary<DiscountType, decimal>`. I don't think that a discount is set in stone.

Comment: Guessing.... Will probably be schooled by someone for this but... Could it be because of enums could be used as bitflags and floating numbers don't work with bitwise operators?

Comment: Enums dont really hold a value (technically they do) they are intended to enumerate a set of possible choices. The underlying value of them is neccessary to efficiently store them. I agree with @TimSchmelter - I would not use them to store real world data, but as a Key to a Dictionary.

Comment: Agree with PhillipH and Borgleader.  Enums should not be used in calculations.  If you need calculations, then constants would be preferable.  If you make them static, they will have a nice syntax like Enums.